# How to add self node & arrowed edges to an Interactive Network Graph Visualization in Bokeh Python

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to create an interactive visualization for a State Transition Matrix where it highlights all the state transitions and I can interact by hovering over the edges and nodes, and it highlights the tooltip and the nearby node connections. a static example looks something like this

[image]

till now, I've tried making a graph in `bokeh` and it's meeting all the requirements except it's not creating self-node edges or showing a directed transition between states.

Can anyone suggest how self-node edges and arrow-ed edges can be achieved in bokeh?

[image]

I was able to find a small package in its beta version called `gravis` which met all my requirements but currently, it doesn't have any active support so I'm not able to use it in my project

[image]

Comment: Concerning the meta [What's the difference between "How can I do X?" and "What library does X?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256226/21350362), this question should be rephrase a bit, otherwise it has high chances to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: @Dmitry thanks for the point out, have edited the question and made it specific to bokeh.